# What's this floating number that keeps appearing if I'm running Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

It doesn't always appear, and other times it takes several hours to appear, or sometimes within a matter of minutes of opening Visual Studio.

A number that is some kind of small window that overlays every open window (think Task Managers "Always on top"). I've only ever seen it be "1" or "2" never any other numbers I don't think, and also the number isn't affected by the number of instances of Visual Studio I'm running. What the heck is going on?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that is a third party program. What have you installed on your PC ?

Comment: This does appear to be connected to Visual Studio since its appears on the desktop itself, while it might be caused by Visual Studio, the floating number is being created by something other than Visual Studio.  Can you recreate this behavior on a virtual machine

Comment: It disappears the second I close VS

Comment: What add-ins do you have for VS?

Comment: Resharper, that's it.

Comment: Looks similar to the Tab Order numbers shown via the View menu.  Not that this helps in any way!

Comment: Do these numbers repeat or do they go from 1 to n ? Any correspondence with the position of open windows on the task bar ?

Comment: I've only ever seen the number be 1 or 2, and there seems to be no link with task bar.

Comment: @user9993: Does pressing NumLock get rid of it by any chance?

Comment: This is likely from the Notification center.

Comment: Well, I checked the notification counter and it doesn’t have its own window. [Here’s a style comparison](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8LM3v.png), too.

Answer (score 5):

Use Visual Studio itself to determine which process created the overlay.

1. Open "Spy++ (x64)" under TOOLS (menu).
2. Select "Find Window..." under Search (menu).
3. Drag the "Finder Tool" crosshairs to overlay to select it.
4. Click "OK" to navigate to the relevant process.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I will try that and update my question when it next appears. It's been a couple of days so far.

Comment: Still no sign of it appearing again.

Comment: Nope not yet and I was using it a couple of hours ago. It's a real mystery!

Comment: It's been another couple weeks.  Did the number overlay ever return?

Comment: Nope I really really don't understand it. It had been going on and off occasionally for months and as soon as I asked on here it seems to have stopped :/ I'm baffled.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have tried clicking/right-clicking and hovering over this number to see if it does anything or shows more information and nothing happened.

Does it appear for all solutions you work on or only some/one?

It maybe one of the extensions/addins you have installed. You can start Visual Studio in safe mode which will ignore all third party extensions.  From a command prompt, change directory to where you have Visual Studio installed and enter:

```
devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

Wait a while to give the floating number a chance to appear. If it doesn't then you know it is a third party feature you have installed.

Methodically disable one at a time and check if it disappears.  You can get to Extension Manager from the menu. Choose:

1. Tools
2. Extensions and Updates

Here is a link for more information on the Visual Studio Extension Manager.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293638.aspx

Failing all of that, you can turn on Visual Studio logging.  When you notice the floating number appear, check the log to see what executed around the time the number appeared.  To turn on logging, you again need a command prompt in the directory where Visual Studio is installed and enter:

```
devenv.exe /log %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\vslog.txt
```

This will create a text-based log file on your desktop.